# Битрикс - почему после создания инфоблока "Страница не найдена"?

Tags: php, битрикс, битрикс24

Создал инфоблок "Статьи" по аналогу блока новостей в типах инфоблоков.
Добавил статью.
В основное разделе статью вижу, но когда нажимаю на детальный просмотр - пишет страница не найдена.
Настройки инфоблока:

URL страницы информационного блока:#SITE_DIR#/article/

URL страницы детального просмотра: #SITE_DIR#/article/#ELEMENT_CODE#/

Содержимое файла index.php , который лежит в директории article:

```
<?
require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/bitrix/header.php");
$APPLICATION->SetTitle("Статьи");
?><?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent("bitrix:news", "flat", array(
    "IBLOCK_TYPE" => "article",
    "IBLOCK_ID" => "5",
    "TEMPLATE_THEME" => "site",
    "NEWS_COUNT" => "10",
    "USE_SEARCH" => "N",
    "USE_RSS" => "Y",
    "NUM_NEWS" => "20",
    "NUM_DAYS" => "180",
    "YANDEX" => "N",
    "USE_RATING" => "N",
    "USE_CATEGORIES" => "N",
    "USE_REVIEW" => "N",
    "USE_FILTER" => "N",
    "SORT_BY1" => "ACTIVE_FROM",
    "SORT_ORDER1" => "DESC",
    "SORT_BY2" => "SORT",
    "SORT_ORDER2" => "ASC",
    "CHECK_DATES" => "Y",
    "SEF_MODE" => "Y",
    "SEF_FOLDER" => "/article/",
    "AJAX_MODE" => "N",
    "AJAX_OPTION_SHADOW" => "Y",
    "AJAX_OPTION_JUMP" => "N",
    "AJAX_OPTION_STYLE" => "Y",
    "AJAX_OPTION_HISTORY" => "N",
    "CACHE_TYPE" => "A",
    "CACHE_TIME" => "36000000",
    "CACHE_FILTER" => "N",
    "CACHE_GROUPS" => "Y",
    "DISPLAY_PANEL" => "Y",
    "SET_TITLE" => "Y",
    "SET_STATUS_404" => "Y",
    "INCLUDE_IBLOCK_INTO_CHAIN" => "N",
    "ADD_SECTIONS_CHAIN" => "N",
    "ADD_ELEMENT_CHAIN" => "Y",
    "USE_PERMISSIONS" => "N",
    "PREVIEW_TRUNCATE_LEN" => "",
    "LIST_ACTIVE_DATE_FORMAT" => "d.m.Y",
    "LIST_FIELD_CODE" => array(
        0 => "",
        1 => "",
    ),
    "LIST_PROPERTY_CODE" => array(
        0 => "",
        1 => "",
    ),
    "HIDE_LINK_WHEN_NO_DETAIL" => "N",
    "DISPLAY_NAME" => "Y",
    "META_KEYWORDS" => "-",
    "META_DESCRIPTION" => "-",
    "BROWSER_TITLE" => "-",
    "DETAIL_ACTIVE_DATE_FORMAT" => "d.m.Y",
    "DETAIL_FIELD_CODE" => array(
        0 => "",
        1 => "",
    ),
    "DETAIL_PROPERTY_CODE" => array(
        0 => "",
        1 => "",
    ),
    "DETAIL_DISPLAY_TOP_PAGER" => "N",
    "DETAIL_DISPLAY_BOTTOM_PAGER" => "Y",
    "DETAIL_PAGER_TITLE" => "Страница",
    "DETAIL_PAGER_TEMPLATE" => "arrows",
    "DETAIL_PAGER_SHOW_ALL" => "Y",
    "DISPLAY_TOP_PAGER" => "N",
    "DISPLAY_BOTTOM_PAGER" => "Y",
    "PAGER_TITLE" => "Статьи",
    "PAGER_SHOW_ALWAYS" => "N",
    "PAGER_TEMPLATE" => "arrows",
    "PAGER_DESC_NUMBERING" => "N",
    "PAGER_DESC_NUMBERING_CACHE_TIME" => "36000000",
    "PAGER_SHOW_ALL" => "N",
    "DISPLAY_DATE" => "Y",
    "DISPLAY_PICTURE" => "Y",
    "DISPLAY_PREVIEW_TEXT" => "Y",
    "AJAX_OPTION_ADDITIONAL" => "",
    "SLIDER_PROPERTY" => "PICS_NEWS",
    "SEF_URL_TEMPLATES" => array(
        "article" => "",
        "section" => "",
        "detail" => "#ELEMENT_CODE#/",
        "search" => "search/",
        "rss" => "rss/",
        "rss_section" => "#SECTION_ID#/rss/",
    )
    ),
    false
);?><?require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/bitrix/footer.php");?>
```

Comment: Внимательно посмотрите по какому URL вы переходите на детальную страницу статьи, потому что из настроек инфоблока #SITE_DIR#/article/#ELEMENT_CODE#/ у вас получиться 2 / в ссылки на статью, по тому что #SITE_DIR# это и есть / а вы еще добавили /article/ и получаем //article/code-elementa/ и компонент не найдет такую страницу, если не поможет, советую посмотреть добавлено ли правило обработки страниц в urlrewrite.php

Comment: Спасибо. Первый совет не помог, второй помог. Небыло прописанов  в urlrewrite.php .